# C#: Trying to copy CSV file into an array

Tags: c#, string, csv, split, char

I have this code to copy my csv into an array:

```
var filePath = @"C:\Users\sti\source\repos\AutoAppr\AutoAppr\bin\Debug\Spreadsheet.csv";
var data = File.ReadLines(filePath).Select(x => x.Split(',')).ToArray();
```

This works, however my csv has strings separated with quotes/commas like:
`"red","green","blue"`

Some of the fields have commas in them so it breaks them up.

I tried editing `x.Split(',')` into `x.Split('\",\"')` however this only seems to accept characters. Is there a fix for this?

Thanks

Comment: It might be useful to use a CSV parsing library (you can search for your favorite), which will take care of all these edge cases for you.

Comment: Using string.Split is the wrong way (a CSV parser is the right way), but for future reference you were looking for [this overload of String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-6.0#system-string-split(system-string()-system-stringsplitoptions)).

Answer (score 0):

This worked perfectly thanks to Andrew:

```
string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { "\",\"" };
var filePath = @"C:\Users\sti\source\repos\AutoAppr\AutoAppr\bin\Debug\Spreadsheet.csv";
var data = File.ReadLines(filePath).Select(x => x.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None)).ToArray();
```